# How to setup nvmetcli for FC loopback mode?

Tags: linux-kernel, fibre-channel, nvme

I have a NVMe SSD, KC1000, from Kingston and a HBA, QLE2672 2-port 16Gb Fibre Channel Adapter, from QLogic and are installed on Linux kernel 4.16.6.

Then I would like to set up a scenario which has a fc loop mode which is to use the sole FC HBA as an initiator and target, to access the NVMe SSD as a NVMe target.

I installed all the required drivers, i.e. nvme-core, nvme, nvme-fabrics, nvme-fc, nvmet, nvmet-fc, nvme-loop, nvme-fcloop and qla2xxx, in order and nvmetcli and followde through settings on [nvmetcli(8)](http://git.infradead.org/users/hch/nvmetcli.git/blob/HEAD:/Documentation/nvmetcli.txt).

But when I reach line 212, "create testnqn", on the link, I had error message as
"Could not symlink testnqn in configFS: [Errno 6] No such device or address".

I hacked the kernel source and found it seems there are device attributes on the path, "/sys/devices/virtual/fcloop/ctl/", to fill. But I can't figure out what the string and format are.

Any clues are welcome.